# Facebook Cdata ODBC connector not getting likes table data

Tags: facebook, odbc, cdata, cdata-drivers

I have installed CData ODBC driver and Setup DSN Connection for my facebook page using that driver.

The problem is that i am not getting facebook Page "likes" table data as mentioned in their document 
http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RBE/odbc/pg_alltables.htm

Whereas I am able to access "post" table easily, Is there anyway to resolve this issue?
I have already test the connection and authenticate this connection

**Here is my DSN Connection config**

[image: DSN Connection]

Note: I have used ODBC Connector in Alteryx and Tableau to check the driver